# Is it possible to loop a counter in a property using Stylus?

Tags: css, stylus

I'm trying to create multiple columns without creating one by one using Stylus. That's what I've done so far:

```
for i in (1..2)
   .column-{i}
      /* random-prop */
```

The compiled version of the code showed:

```
.column-1 { /* random-prop */ }
.column-2 { /* random-prop */ }
```

I've tried to create multiple variables like those above (just for testing):

```
column-size-1 = 100%
column-size-2 = 50%
```

But when I try to do the same thing I've done before:

```
for i in (1..2)
   .column-{i}
      width column-size-{i}
```

It doesn't work and I don't know why (I'm trying to learn something new and Stylus appeared).

What is the better way to create multiple columns in Stylus, avoiding many replications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I may make a correction: the arrays start at zero so you have to write:

```
colors = #f00, #0f0
for i in (0..1)
   .column-{i}
      background colors[i]
```

You can enhance the loop using the `colors` variable instead number to loop through the array, this way if values are added to the list don't have to change the number in the loop.

**Stylus**

```
colors = #f00, #0f0, #000
for color, i in colors
  i=i+1
  .column-{i}
    background color
```

**Output**

```
.column-1 {
  background: #f00;
}
.column-2 {
  background: #0f0;
}
.column-3 {
  background: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a answer... I've created an array (that was hard to find in Documentation) and called it in loop, example:

```
colors = #f00, #0f0
for i in (1..2)
   .column-{i}
      background colors[i]
```